# Мониторинг Дизель генераторных установок java

Tags: java, com-порт, modbus

Мне надо написать мониторинг ДГУ, протокол передачи данных я буду использовать modbus, подключаться через com-port и ethernet, как я могу получить данные из контроллера генератора, а именно: скорость двигателя, частота генератора, частота сети, давление масла и т.п ?

Comment: вам нужна какая-нибудь библиотека, реализующая modbus на java (я пользовался [j2mod](https://sourceforge.net/projects/j2mod/), проект был небольшой, поэтому не могу сказать, насколько библиотека хороша), и документация на контроллер, в которой указано, по каким адресам лежат нужные параметры.

Comment: Спасибо, довольно исчерпывающий ответ, напишите в ответ поставлю плюсик, для modbus использую jamod-1.2-SNAPSHOT, вот про доки на контроллер не знал, кстати я так понял modbus работает по принципу "ведущий-ведомый", не в курсе где про этот принцип можно почитать, ибо работал я только на клиент-сервер -  http протокол.

Comment: На сколько я понимаю вот это http://imgur.com/iDMndr7 и есть те адреса по которым обращаться за параметрами ?

Comment: да, похоже на адреса регистров. Ведущий-ведомый просто означает, что ведомые устройства могут только отвечать на запрос ведущего, и никогда не начинают передавать в сеть сами.

Comment: zRrr в моем случае на сколько я понял ведомый - будет мой код, а контроллер мне отправит данные ?

Comment: думаю, наоборот, у устройства есть какой-то адрес, и вы должны будете его периодически опрашивать

Comment: Ага, вы развеяли туман в моей голове, спасибо большое! Буду делать)

Comment: Я извиняюсь, но все же, как открыть соединение с com-портом и прочитать данные по регистрам я примерно понял, но не могу понять как же java узнает к какому порту мне подключиться, ведь их может одновременно в комп подключено быть несколько ? Есть параметр portname я подозреваю что это оно и есть, но тогда как мне узнать имя того порта который я подключу или как же к нужному мне порту подключиться ? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А есть где то документация на j2mod ? Или она такая же как и у jamod ? Я слышал j2mod это новая версия jamod'a.